# I need MYSQL query solution

Tags: mysql

I have these tables and in one query with username and password (at login) I want to select the data from the right table.
example: in the user table there is the field permission.
admin has privileges 1, vendor has privileges 2, and customer has privileges 3.
thanks.

```
+------------+--+----------+--+-----------+--+-------------+
|    user    |  |  admin   |  |  vendor   |  |  customer   |
+------------+--+----------+--+-----------+--+-------------+
| id_user    |  | id_admin |  | id_vendor |  | id_customer |
| username   |  | id_user  |  | id_user   |  | id_user     |
| password   |  | name     |  | name      |  | name        |
| permission |  | surname  |  | surname   |  | surname     |
+------------+--+----------+--+-----------+--+-------------+
```

Comment: It is clear your solution will be a SQL statement with some JOIN clauses, but it is impossible to help you specifically until you better explain the relational requirements. How does `user.permission` map to `admin` "privileges"?

Comment: OK thanks. I tried and it works with these queries. $query = "SELECT * FROM  user INNER JOIN admin ON admin.id_user = user.id_user WHERE user = '$username' and password = '$password' limit 1";  but I would add
     "if (permission == 1) for admin or if (permission == 2) for vendor or if (permission == 3) for customer"
and perform a single query, making automatically select the correct table, to retrieve the data.

Comment: Having a conditional join to different tables based on a column value like this is considered very bad practice and usually has a root cause in incorrect relational DB design. It is possible to condense this down into just one SQL query but it will be expensive (3 joins every time where 2 are always unnecessary) and require null checking on the result. Without making any schema changes, it is probably best to leave it as a 2-stage query. First query the user table, then next query only the table needed based on the `permission` value of the first query's result.

Comment: Why is the user's name and surname associated with their permissions? It would seem to make more sense to put `name` and `surname` in the `user` table.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on my comment, there is no reason (barring extensive refactoring time commitments) that these 4 tables could not be de-normalized into a single table with all the same information as follows:

```
+------------+
|    user    |
+------------+
| id_user    |
| username   |
| password   |
| permission |
| name       |
| surname    |
+------------+
```

Here `permission` represents the type of user (admin, vendor, or customer). If a user could possibly belong to more than one category (eg, a user is both a customer and a vendor), then you can just consider `permission` as a [(bit) flag field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_field) (or you could break it out into 3 separate boolean fields `is_X`). There are many downstream benefits to doing this that may not be immediately obvious. For example, you have a single `id_user` foreign key now into any other related tables, instead of potentially 4 disparate foreign keys.

Always try to keep in mind that time-tested rule of relational database design: ***"Normalize until it hurts, then de-normalize until it works"***. The motivation for de-normalization is almost always expensive queries that would require constant JOINs or unnecessary bifurcations of keys.